# Identify NULLs in a vector

Tags: r, vector, null

Consider the following vector `a`

```
a <- c(NULL, 1, 2, "A", NULL, NA)
```

I am trying to identify the positions of `NULL` in the vector. However, `NULL` is not a string. I am wondering why `is.null` does not work similar to `is.na` which returns the positions of the `NA`s in the vector.

```
> is.na(a)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> is.null(a)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: You can't have `NULL` as an element in a vector. Take a look at your vector - it only contains 4 elements.

Comment: Oh right. So NULL in a vector or data.frame can only exists as "NULL". So as a character string. Is that correct?

Comment: but note that lists **can** contain `NULL`s -- look at `list(1,2,NULL,"A")`

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, agreed. I'm trying to construct an example.

Comment: So:  why are you using NULL in the first place?  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Well, I am processing a lot of data in the moment and some of the values are "NULL", "NA" or NA. I obvisouly haven't seen any NULL's yet but I thought when I wrote code to remove the other values why not include NULL in case it appears. But now I know it cannot appear in a vector or data.frame

Comment: Another way to remember this is that `NULL` has length 0. `NA` has length 1.

Comment: If you're reading data in from text files, and missing-ness is encoded with multiple symbols, you might investigate using the `na.strings` argument to force them all to be interpreted as `NA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `is.null` is used to check whether an object is identical to `NULL`. The `NULL` values are not part of the vector, they are "nothing".

Hence your vector does not include any `NULL`s but the other values only:

```
[1] "1" "2" "A" NA
```

The information about the `NULL`s you used to create the vector is lost and cannot be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

From the R [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf):

> NULL It is used whenever there is a need to indicate or specify that
>   an object is **absent**.

So you can't identify the position of absents in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

NULL cannot be a member of a vector, only a list.  NA is used to mark missing data in vectors.

NULL is a special data object that says something like "this is undefined" and is returned by expressions and functions that  have an undefined value.